# How to open Viber app in Flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to open Viber app (Android / Windows) from flutter web application. I tried using `url_launcher` but it does not work.

The URL to open Viber chat is `viber://chat?number=xxx`. How can I call this from flutter web app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution. I used `html` package

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
```

After that

```
html.window.open('viber://chat?number=xxx', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package [Flutter AppAvailability Plugin](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_appavailability)

Comment: This does not work in flutter web. I have found a solution. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the same solution but only for a mobile app, Google gives me only this question. So, I decided to write the research results here. Maybe it will come in handy.

For a mobile app, you can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

```
launch('viber://chat?number=$phoneNumber');
```

If you want to open the conversation with a predefined text, you can write like this:

```
launch('viber://chat/?number=$phoneNumber&draft=$yourMessage');
```

Please note, if Viber is not installed on your device, the `launch` method throws an error.

Comment: This isn't a hierarchical URI